# Passing variables to nodes in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have what looks to me to be a bug, but I'm not sure, and either way I'd love to know a way to work around it:

Here's two simple groovy scripts that should easily demonstrate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def test_func = { var ->
   println("${var}")
}

stage ("TEST") {
   parallel(
      "Side A" : { test_func("SIDE A") },
      "Side B" : { test_func("SIDE B") })
}
```

This one functions as you would expect.  The relevant output from Jenkins:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (TEST)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [Side A] { (Branch: Side A)
[Pipeline] [Side B] { (Branch: Side B)
[Pipeline] [Side A] echo
[Side A] SIDE A
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] [Side B] echo
[Side B] SIDE B
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Okay, lets say I want to do the same thing, but grab a node this time for each side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def test_func = { var ->
   node("mynode") {
      println("${var}")
   }
}

stage ("TEST") {
   parallel(
      "Side A" : { test_func("SIDE A") },
      "Side B" : { test_func("SIDE B") })
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that the variable "var" is not being set how one would expect:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (TEST)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [Side A] { (Branch: Side A)
[Pipeline] [Side B] { (Branch: Side B)
[Pipeline] [Side A] node
[Pipeline] [Side B] node
[Side B] Running on mynode in /path/to/workspace/branch-FWZZDEZOFZMJGIPOKAJQ7GY7YR7WZLVYNUGHCQ4VVMNFW25VVVBA@2
[Side A] Running on mynode in /path/to/workspace/branch-FWZZDEZOFZMJGIPOKAJQ7GY7YR7WZLVYNUGHCQ4VVMNFW25VVVBA
[Pipeline] [Side A] {
[Pipeline] [Side B] {
[Pipeline] [Side A] echo
[Side A] SIDE B
[Pipeline] [Side A] }
[Pipeline] [Side B] echo
[Side B] SIDE B
[Pipeline] [Side B] }
[Pipeline] [Side A] // node
[Pipeline] [Side B] // node
[Pipeline] [Side A] }
[Pipeline] [Side B] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Any idea why this is happening?  How can I get this variable passed correctly to my node?

Comment: It could be related to https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481.